# How to save my jquery array to php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I have a script that gets the contents of a table that i added.

And i want to do is save the content into a database.

In the picture the table and the content of my dataSet variable that i get from the table.

i check the dataSet and alert it to check if it has value.

My problem is im having trouble saving the array that i passed to php cause its not working its not saving. I got an error in my saveTable.php invalid argument foreach.

[image]

script:

```
var names = [].map.call($("#myTable2 thead th"), function (th) {
    return $(th).text();
});


var x = [].map.call($("#myTable2 tbody tr"), function (tr) {
    return [].reduce.call(tr.cells, function (p, td, i) {
        p[names[i]] = $(td).text();
        return p;
    }, {});
});

var dataSet = JSON.stringify(x);
alert(dataSet);

$.ajax(
    {
    url: "saveTable.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { tableArray: dataSet},
    success: function (result) {

    }
});
```

saveTable.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "test";

$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);
$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$tableArray = isset($_REQUEST['tableArray']) ? $_REQUEST['tableArray'] : "";

$sql = "INSERT INTO viewTables (name, age, gender, action) VALUES (:name, :age, :gender, :action)";
$sth = $dbc->prepare($sql);
foreach( $tableArray As $v){
    $sth->bindValue(':name', $v[0], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $sth->bindValue(':age', $v[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':gender', $v[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':action', $v[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);      
    $sth->execute();
}

?>
```

new error:

[image]

Comment: once `print_r($_REQUEST); exit;` in php code. whether is it posting or not.

Comment: I think you just forgot to parse JSON : `json_decode($_POST['tableArray'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that you are trying to use a `String` type in the `foreach` loop. Try:

```
$tableArray = isset($_REQUEST['tableArray']) ? json_decode($_REQUEST['tableArray']) : array();
```

This should make it work. Good luck, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the string to an array using `json_decode` to be able to use it as an array.